# Looking for Unix style 'getopt' command line parsing in a Windows batch file

Tags: windows, parsing, batch-file, command-line, cmd

Can anyone help me find something to parse command line args in a Windows batch file like one would do in a Unix shell script using getopt/getopts?  It doesn't have to be all Posix-y; just something that I can specify what switches I expect, which of them require/allow an argument.  They don't need to be "long" switches; single characters will work.

It can be an external .exe that the batch file calls.  It has to be freely distributable.

Comment: I think this is the right answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973824/windows-bat-file-optional-argument-parsing

Answer (score 16):

You can you something like this (-h has no args, hence no shift after that, -b and -s take additional args, so shift them).

```
:GETOPTS
 if /I "%1" == "-h" goto Help
 if /I "%1" == "-b" set BASE=%2 & shift
 if /I "%1" == "-s" set SQL=%2 & shift
 shift
if not "%1" == "" goto GETOPTS
```

Comment: it's worth adding here that /I enables case insensitive comparisons - thus both -S and -s would enable the SQL line - and may not be desirable for all cases.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as getopt/getopts-like parsing of commandline arguments as you know from Unix/Linux.

Batch files only know about `%0`, `%1`, `%2`, ... and `%*` (and such variations as  `%~0`, `%~1`... which remove quotes, should there be ones around an arg).

Up to nine arguments. If there are more to process, you can use `shift` (equiv. to `shift /1` if `enableextensions` happened) to remove the first arg and shift the rest.

Basically that's it.

---

<sup>(Maybe you should explain more what exactly you are trying to achieve with the batch, why you must use batch, and what your other external constraints are.)</sup>