CMD command line argument passing in batch script
using CMD and batch scripting, how can I give in my batch script a command line argument like /user=something and then how to get this value inside the script ?
I tried the below simple script but it does not work.
The script is:
@echo off
setlocal

REM Loop through each command-line argument
for %%A in (%*) do (
    REM Check if the argument starts with "/user="
    if /i "%%A"=="%A:/user=*" (
        REM Extract the value after "/user="
        set "user=%%A:~6%"
    )
)

REM Check if the user variable was set and display it
if defined user (
    echo User is %user%
) else (
    echo No user argument was provided
)

The result was:
No user argument was provided
How can accomplish it ?
Thanks

This answer by Dave Benham is required reading, imho.

There's some things to keep in mind when parsing arguments using a plain For:

Unqouted Arguments will be split using the standard for delimiters, which include: ' ' ',' '=' ';'
'?' and '*' are wildcards of the for command and will result in undesired behaviour if provided by the user.
'^' '&' '>' '<' '|' '!' and '%' are considered poison characters and can likewise result in unintended behaviour and / or code execution.

All that said, if the input can be trusted, what your aiming for can be done by using a variable and it's defined status to effect a switch statement when the /User string is encountered.
@echo off
Setlocal EnableExtensions
Set "UserArg="
For %%G in (%*)do (
  If defined UserArg (
    Set "UserArg="
    Set "User=%%~G"
  )
  If /i "%%G" == "/User" Set "UserArg=1"
)

Echo(%User%

Pause
Endlocal & Goto:eof


what modifications should be done in order to support other arguments alongside with this one, e.g. if I want to have /g /r /f  etc   what modifications your script will required ?   Thanks

@mikekgr You could duplicate the same conditional method used for /user, using different variables for each supported switch. Note, that would assume each switch will always have an argument. Resolving such (as well as any potential special character handling, enacting argument defaults etc, would be beyond the scope of your initial question, and should be asked in a new question.
A basic example can be found here for testing the presence of a switch. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22735759/12343998
Handling combinations of switches that may or may not have subarguments is more involved

@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET "Uname=%*"
rem find whether /username= is in the whole tail
:again
SET "unamex=%uname:*/username=%"
IF "%unamex%"=="%uname%" SET "user="&GOTO done

IF "%unamex:~0,1%" neq "=" SET "uname=%unamex%"&GOTO again
FOR %%B IN (%unamex:~1%) DO seT "user=%%B"&GOTO done

:done

IF DEFINED user SET "user=%user:~0,6%"

ECHO user is "%user%"
goto :eof

Note that for in your code sees = as a separator.
You cannot substring metavariables like %%A without transferring it to a user variable and either invoking delayedexpansion or calling a subroutine.
First, set uname to the command-line tail
set unamex to uname, with everything up to the string /username replaced by nothing. Note that = is required syntax, so the = in the detected string is thus assigned to unamex.
If the strings in uname and unamex are the same, then /username did not exist in the text, so set user and done.
If not, then unamex contains the tail after /username. If the first character is not =, we have something like /username3, so examine the remainder of the line by putting the remaining tail into username and trying again.
Otherwise, we've found /username=, so grab the first token from unamex, bar the first character (=) and assign to user and we're done.
Then restrict to 6 characters.
Note: I prefer to avoid ADFNPSTXZ (in either case) as metavariables (loop-control variables) as ADFNPSTXZ are also metavariable-modifiers which can lead to difficult-to-find bugs (See for/f from the prompt for documentation)
