# How to pass ssh passphrase in batch file windows?

Tags: batch-file, winscp

how do i provide a passphrase key in windows batch file to automate ssh upload to server?

```
ECHO OFF
ECHO open Abc@142.15.0.178
```

then the server ask for passphrase key that i created. How to put the passphrase key into the batch file?

Comment: Is it not more secure to add the key to the arguments? Because credentials in scripts is not prefered. Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494898/looking-for-unix-style-getopt-command-line-parsing-in-a-windows-batch-file

Comment: @Thomas, thanks for your reply. Yes it is less secure but the requirement is like that. I've never put the key inside the arguments before that's why i don't know how to do it.